# How to replace column names with a value of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have table A like below:

```
ID  QuestionCode   Question
1    Q1            What is your name
2    Q2            How old are you
3    Q3            Where are you from
```

Also, I have table B like below:

```
UserId  Q1     Q2   Q3
1       Ahmad  22   Egypt
2       John   31   USA
3       Daniel 32   Mexico
```

What I want is to create a view using the question itself instead of the its code in the column name like:

```
UserId    What Is Your Name    How old are you    Where are you from
1         Ahmad                22                 Egypt
2         John                 31                 USA
3         Daniel               32                 Mexico
```

What is the best way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated ... Missed the 2016 tag**

SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.
This leaves Dynamic SQL.

Here is a working example of the Dynamic SQL

```
Declare @tsql nvarchar(max) = N'Select top 1 * from Answers 

Select @tsql = 'Select '+stuff((Select ',' +expr From (
                                                      select expr=concat(coalesce(quotename(Question),Name),'=',Name)
                                                       From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql,null,null )   A
                                                       Left Join Questions B on B.QuestionCode=A.name
                                                      ) src For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')+' From Answers'
 
Exec(@tsql)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pivot you're describing isn't easy to do in straight SQL; you could write some dynamic SQL to create column names and subqueries for the second table based on the first, but to do this but can be rather fiddly and is certainly an easy way to break things if you get it wrong.

There's an alternative approach highlighted at https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/easier-way-pivoting-data-sql-server/; whether that's simpler than the dynamic SQL option very much depends on your experience level.